# Android disable radio group in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, android-xml, radio-group

In my android application, I need to disable radio group in xml layout. I searched, but I found only through pro-grammatically not in xml layout.

My code is here

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/menu1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="170dp"
        android:layout_y="100dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yes" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No" />
</RadioGroup>
```

I've tried with android:enabled="false" but it is not supported by Radio Group. But it works in RadioButton as

```
      <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="Yes" />
```

Now my question is If my RadioGroup contains 10 RadioButtons, I want to set enable=false only for the RadioGroup, not for every individual RadioButton. So how can I disable the entire RadioGroup instead of disabling RadioButtons?

I need only in xml layout. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please stop doing those pointless edits just to get your question bumped. Use a bounty if you want more attention.

Answer (score 7):

Use the following attribute

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Comment: This worked for me, but you have to add it to each RadioButton, and not the RadioGroup.

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right  there is no   property given for radio group for disable it.

you can not find any method to do like in this developer site [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

> Now my question is If my RadioGroup contains 10 RadioButtons, I want
>   to set enable=false only for the RadioGroup, not for every individual
>   RadioButton. So how can I disable the entire RadioGroup instead of
>   disabling RadioButtons?

All you can do to disable it is in java code of activity .

```
for (int i = 0; i <group.getChildCount(); i++) 
{
    group.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);      
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know in java code. But, I want to do in design time. I have to change my idea

Comment: @ling.s using RadioGroup there is no option to set it form XML it seems